# Safari and Firefox displaying different colors than Chrome

Tags: display, color

On [this website](https://www.hostpoint.ch), the blue button has the defined color `#1E9AE2`. In Safari and Firefox on macOS, this color is displayed as `#449AE0`:

[image]

In this screenshot, Safari is on the left, and Chrome to the right.

If I switch the following setting to "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", Safari and Firefox display it like the others too:

[image]

What's the reason for this difference?

Do all macOS computers have this setting as a default?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in color rendering is because of color profiles. Some browsers support color profiles, others don't. Embedding color profiles in your images will make their file sizes a bit larger, but will cause truer colors across browsers.

Please see:

- https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/
- http://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/
- https://fstoppers.com/education/how-your-web-browser-affects-way-colors-are-rendered-77241

Comment: The *login* button is no picture and consequently doesn't contain a profile! Instead it's probably defined in the css with: `background-color: #1E9AE2;`

Comment: That second link explains it all (including CSS elements) under "Why tagging images for the web is not a complete answer?". In the end, it doesn't even matter. Everyone will have differently, and often ill-, configured displays.